# Nothing happens when using I.attachFile to upload a document

Tags: playwright, codeceptjs

Is a drag-and-drop field required for the `I.attachFile('element', 'filePath')` to work? Because currently nothing happens when I try using the attachFile method. No error message or any issues displayed even when using --verbose.

This is the element where I try to attach my file `//input[@type='file']`. I also verified that I have the correct fileName and filePath since I tried using a wrong file name and it returned an error.

I am currently using:

- codeceptjs: ^3.3.6,
- playwright: ^1.19.0

I tried changing the file I'm about to upload to see if my file is the problem, but when I do upload the file manually in the page it works as expected; but when trying to do it in my code, nothing happens.

- Expected: The uploaded file's name should be displayed
- Actual: Nothing happens; no file name displayed; no error message returned in the logs

Comment: Can you post your code snippet please?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setInputFiles` method. Docs [here](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-elementhandle#element-handle-set-input-files)

Example:

```
const input = await page.locator('//input[@type='file']');
await input.setInputFiles('./files/photos/myPhoto.jpeg'); // location of file
```

The file will be uploaded when you click on submit/send/upload button which will trigger the form submit event.